# encrypting in Objective-C decrypting nodejs

Tags: objective-c, node.js, cryptography

I'm encrypting some text i want to send to a server and I have no problems encrypting it, and decrypting it in Objective-C but when I send it to the nodejs server the result by decrypting it never comes right the encrypted data comes always the same... I think the problem is how I use the crypto library, here's my Xcode code:

```
    NSString * key =@"1234567890123456";
NSString * url = @"http://flystory.herokuapp.com/register";


NSString *post = @"hola mundo!!!!!!!!!!";
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
NSError *e;
CCCryptorStatus err;
postData = [postData dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm:kCCAlgorithmAES128 key:key options:kCCOptionECBMode error:&err];
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);


NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"post"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"body" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *r, NSData *d, NSError *e) {
                           if (e) NSLog(@"%@",e.description);
                           else [self handleRespondedData:d];
                       }];

postData = [postData decryptedDataUsingAlgorithm:kCCAlgorithmAES128 key:key options:kCCOptionECBMode error:&err];
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
```

to encrypt I'm using this NSData extension contained in the NSData+CommonCrypto.h/m in https://github.com/Gurpartap/AESCrypt-ObjC

my Node.JS code goes as follows:

```
    var express = require("express");
    var app = express(express.bodyParser());
    //...
    app.post("*", function(request, response) {
var body = '';


    request.setEncoding('hex');
    request.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
        var crypto=require('crypto');
        var decipher=crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-ecb', '1234567890123456');
        decipher.setAutoPadding(auto_padding=false);
        var enc = decipher.update(body, 'hex', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');            


        console.log('encrypted: ' + body);
        console.log('decrypted: ' + enc);

    });

    request.on('end', function () {

        // use POST
        route(handle, request.path, response, body);
    });

});
```

Comment: You are making two large steps at once: encryption and transmission. Break that down into separate tests. First the encryption, then transmission of that data.

Comment: I did that already, i tested encryption/decryption both on xcode and nodejs, both work just fine... the data transmission shows exactly the same data in hex... so i really think there is an option i have to configure either on node or xcode, but i don't really know what it is...

Comment: Are you sure this is correct: `[request setValue:@"body" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`? Check what is actually being sent with Charles Proxy.

Comment: already tried removing both these lines "[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"body" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];" neither made a difference, and in the three cases the received body was teh same which corresponded to the encrypted xcode data, so i doubt the problem is there...

Comment: @heczaco, did you find what was wrong after all? I face the exact same problem.

Comment: @giorgos29cm no, not yet, I stopped my project because of work and personal issues, just until now I'm retaking it, if you found the problem it would be very nice to know